# Let $f\in L^1$ and $g\in L^{\infty}$ then $f.g\in L^1$ and $\int{|f.g|\leq ||f|_1 .||g||_\infty}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f\in L^1$ and $g\in L^{\infty}$ then $f.g\in L^1$ and $\int{|f.g|\leq ||f|_1 .||g||_\infty}$

I think this can be solved using Holder Inequality but i don't have a clear idea of how solve this type of exercise. Can someone help me?

Comment: This is the Hölder inequality for $p=1$, $q=\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int|fg| \leq \int|f||g| \leq \int|f|||g||_{\infty}=||g||_{\infty}\int|f|=||f||_1||g||_{\infty}$$